# PNG images not displaying in HTML + node.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

Application is written using Angular and node.js. There is some problem with png images not displaying. This happens only on Win server, on Linux it works properly.

This works: `<img src="/assets/images/logo.jpg" />`

This doesn't : `<img src="/assets/images/logo.png" />`

Side note, i'm using express with node.

Comment: What does dev tools network tell you? Problem won't be client side except for possibly using bad paths in `src`

Comment: You haven't given enough information. Show your code.

Comment: @charlietfl I get Status Code:304 Not Modified which is the same status as for .jpg


MattHarrison I would if I knew what to show, I really cannot narrow the problem down. I have two separated folders serving client and servers side. Images folder is in client side. I tried with different node modules, different version etc.. with no luck. I have these dependencies added "imagemin-gifsicle": "^2.0.0", "imagemin-jpegtran": "^2.0.0", "imagemin-optipng": "^2.0.1", "imagemin-pngquant": "^2.0.0". png.js is also installed

Comment: @charlietfl Paths are correct. http://localhost:9999/assets/images/a.png this show broken image, this works ok:  http://localhost:9999/assets/images/b.jpg, no error in console

Comment: sounds like some problem in your build process when they are optimized

Comment: have you checked if that image exist by hitting the path in your browser address bar

Comment: in your server.js can you try the following : app.use('/images', express.static(__dirname + '/assets/images'));   before your server.listen and app.get '/'

Answer (score 1):

Ok I finally found a solution. The problem was because project was built on Linux at first and during that process images got corrupted, I simply replaced images with new ones and everything is ok now. Lost couple of days because of this.